# Adding python3.7 to Anaconda path

Tags: python, ubuntu, anaconda, conda

I have anaconda installed on my ubuntu 17.10. It works fine for python 2.7 but I can't use it in python 3.7. Is there a way I can add python3.7 to the anaconda path?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a Python 3.7 environment via:

`$conda create -n Py37 python=3.7`

This will create a new anaconda environment named Py37 containing the python=3.7 package.

Afterwards, you can activate the environment by running:

`$conda activate Py37`

and it should work right out of the box!

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is no. Anaconda (the company) has not packaged Python 3.7 yet (probably due to it being in beta still). In addition, no other channel (that I'm aware of) has packaged Python 3.7. You can search your configured channels by typing

```
conda search python=3.7
```

or you can look online at Anaconda.org: https://anaconda.org/search?q=%22python%22&sort=_name&sort_order=1&reverse=true&page=14

(that search directs you to the page of the results that as of 07-FEB-2018 shows the Python packages that are uploaded to Anaconda.org. The link/relevant page may change in the future as people add or delete packages)

The long answer is that you can build Python 3.7 yourself from source, if you're so inclined. But that is outside the scope of this Q/A.

Comment: Thank you very much. I guess I'll just have to stick with python2.7 for now.

Comment: @Atia You could also use Python 3.6 which is the current (non-beta) version of Python 3.

Comment: @BlackJack thanks for the tip. I'll get on with that immediately